# have cursor inside double quotes instead of after them in PyCharm

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm

I'm sure there's just a simple setting to resolve this but I can't find it and it's driving me mad.

In PyCharm, when I add `="`, the autocomplete adds the closing `"` for me but it places the cursor after the closing `"`. I'd like it inside the`""`. Is there a setting that will allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Shift+A in pycharm and write cursor. Turn on the second last button which is "UI: Automatically position mouse cursor on default location" Also click the last option "Automatically position mouse cursor on default location" and apply these settings.